# Cant pass array to java spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to store a name of a image, and 2 drop down values into a String array and then pass it as  a array to my controller in spring.It works with json and string but never an array yet

```
@PostMapping(value = "/saveData")
    public ModelAndView save(@RequestBody String choices,@ModelAttribute Data data,Model model){
        System.out.println(choices.toString());


EDIT:
Its in json just so I could test that values were coming in. Now I just need them 2 be an array
```

js

```
$.ajax(url, {
    data: JSON.stringify(choices2),
    datatype : "application/String[]",
    contentType: "text/plain",
    type: 'POST'
});
```

Comment: Well, first of all, `@RequestBody String choices` is not a string array, nor a collection, so it's definitely an important part of the cause of the error. What exception are you getting, BTW?

Comment: No exception its just receiving it as a string not a array(it prints as a string when i println).When i put String[] choices i get a Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type.What must i change in my controller

Comment: It could be a problem with the content type; you could try `contentType: "application/json"`

Comment: I would actually like it in an array ,the json was just for testing that value is being recieved

Comment: Why you don't use ArrayList? that way you can have a better control of the data

Comment: Would you suggest that as i would be using it for receiving user input to customize 3 products

Comment: What must i change in order to use array or arraylist